# How to call EJB on JBOSS AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, ear

We have this method to call a bean on AS 6:

```
 UserEJB o = (UserEJB) ctx.lookup(<app>/<bean name>/<remote>);
```

What should this be changed to in order to do the same thing on AS 7?

Comment: Have you tried reading the JBoss 7 documentation at all? Its quite complete.

Comment: @Gimby thank you.  I've been reading so much my eyes are crossed.  At one point I saw it should being with "ejb:" and another had "TODO: complete this section".  I am new to this world and obviously confused.  Can you give me a good link?

Comment: @Gimby could this error I'm getting trying to access the bean on the jboss server mean that it is not deployed or for some other reason?
    Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: apprd:4447

Comment: And I see this construciton too: beanRemoteInterface = (Foo) ctx.lookup("myapp/myejbmodule/FooBean!org.myapp.ejb.Foo");

Comment: And I've seen this: RemoteCalculator statelessRemoteCalculator = (RemoteCalculator) context.lookup( "ejb:/jboss-as-ejb-remote-server-side/CalculatorBean!" + RemoteCalculator.class.getName());